# Vk api, как переслать вложения из сообщения от лица бота?

Tags: php, вконтакте

в общем мучаюсь с данной проблемой уже около недели, дело в том что я делаю анонимного чат бота вк, и бот должен принимать сообщения и вложения от одного пользователя и отправлять от своего лица другому, переотправку сообщений я без проблем сделал, а вот на вложениях конкретно увяз, никак не могу взять вложения из сообщения одного пользователя, и отправить другому, перечитал всю доку, писал в тп, везде советуют заливать вложение заново, но как я залью заново в вк вложение которого у меня даже нет? У меня получилось сделать переотправку вложений, но почему-то только себе, с другими пользователями не работает, в общем выручайте.

```
    //Убираем префикс
$mess=mb_strtolower($message);
if(!empty($data->object->message->attachments[0])){
$get_id=$peer_Id;
$type=$data->object->message->attachments[0]->type;
$owner_id=$data->object->message->attachments[0]->$type->owner_id;
$photo_id=$data->object->message->attachments[0]->$type->id;
$access_key=$data->object->message->attachments[0]->$type->access_key;
$request_params = [
'message' => $mess,
'peer_id' => $get_id,
'attachment'=>"{$type}{$owner_id}_{$photo_id}_{$access_key}",
'random_id' => "0",
'access_token' => $token,
'v' => '5.103'
];
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params);
echo 'ok'; 
break; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Как сказано в [официальной документации](https://vk.com/dev/objects/message) каждое сообщение содержит поле `attachments`, в котором передаются все медиа файлы. Вам просто нужно взять оттуда файлы и отправить их. Более подробное описание этого поля представлено [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/objects/attachments_m)

**Update:** Не пытайтесь переслать access key вложения другим пользователям, у вас это не выйдет. Ваши сообщения и соответственно вложения к ним можете просматривать только вы и тот человек, который отправил их вам. Все ваши попытки показать это вложение другим пользователям будут пресечены VK. Скачайте вложение и отправьте его другому пользователю

Comment: Я читал всю документацию, и в тех поддержку писал, оно не работает, я же приложил пример своего кода, он отправляет только мои вложения и только мне,  у других людей оно не работает хоть я и использую ацесс кей вложения

Comment: @user363280 обновил ответ

Comment: В каком смысле скачать, каким образом? Вы предлагаете скачивать мне каждое вложение на пк и заливать на сайт? А иначе я способов не знаю, вк не расчитан видимо на это, т.к методы в документации расчитаны только на загрузку с файлов ПК

Comment: @user363280 Зачем вам скачивать это на свой ПК? Вк предоставляет ссылку на медиа файлы, вы можете скачать их с помощью PHP и потом сразу же отправить так же с помощью PHP

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду ссылку из attachment->sizes->url?, больше никаких ссылок там нет

Comment: Вы предлагаете его качать на сервер?

Comment: Да, эта ссылка, получаете изображение по этой ссылке и отправляете его, сохранять изобржение на сервере не обязательно

Comment: В каком смысле получаете? Мне ведь для отправки нужны данные, не могли бы вы хотя-бы пример показать

Comment: @user363280 отправляете обычный `GET` запрос по указанному URL. Сервер vk вернём вам изображение в байтах. Эти байты отправляете нужному пользователю.

Comment: Все ровно не понятно, какой гет запрос, что именно я должен запрашивать, даже если и так, для отправки вложения в личные сообщения мне нужно указывать его данные в attachment, других способов либо нет либо я о них не знаю, просто отправить байты методом message.send нельзя

Comment: @user363280 я не могу вам всё объяснить, у вас нет базы. Изучите http, узнайте как передаются картинки по http. Это уже никак не связано с vk, так работает весь интернет, это не относится к данному вопросу на stackoverflow. На ваш вопрос на stackoverflow я ответил

Comment: Причем тут http, да я могу отправить в сообщении тупо ссылку, да она будет кликабельна и по переходу на нее там будет нужное изображение, но это не то что надо, я еще раз повторю, для пересылки вложения нужно указывать его данные в аттачмент, тип, айди, овнер айди и т.д, кактм образом я туда байты перекину?

Comment: @user363280 скажите, вы представляете как выглядит отправка файлов между 2 любыми серверами по протоколу http? Сервер vk ничем не отличается, только вам в запросе ещё нужно указать дополнительные поля, которые описаны в документации

Comment: Представляю примерно, когда я работал с документами там уже имеется поле url документа, в нем в ссылке имеется хэш, значит вк при загрузке файла на сервео генерирует хэш для вложения, вы имели ввиду отправлять картинку в байтаз на ее загрузку на сервер вк?  Т.е метод get upload server(ну или что-то вроде этого)

Comment: Сможете написать код за деньги?,  чисто функцию переотпрвки вложений

Comment: @user363280 с PHP не работаю =)